# How to connect to TFS running in home network?

Tags: team-foundation-server, visual-studio

I have two computers in my home network one of them is running TFS. Could someone explain me step by step which configuration should be done in order to connect from another laptop to TFS server?

Computer 1: TFS VS 2010 IIS 7
Computer 2: VS 2008 IIS 7

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

**Server Part** : follow the installation process, it is pretty much straight-forward, and would be too long to detail here.

**Client Part** :

- Install [Team Explorer 2008](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=16338)
- Install [Visual Studio 2008 Service Pack 1](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=10986)
- Install [Team Explorer 2008​URL Patch](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=10834)

**Authentification** : If you are not on a domain, you will need to have the same user/password on the machine. Said user will need to be a valid user of TFS.

Answer (score 0):

You can also just use Team Web Access on TFS 2010 to do some stuff on the TFS server. Use this URL: http://YourServerName:8080/tfs/web *

*this URL assumes you didn't change any of the defaults during setup!